# multivalidation in sharepoint list

Tags: 2016, date-time, validation, column-validation

I am working on sharepoint 2016 and having issue in applying multiple validation between date column

1. Column A should not be less then Column B
2. Column F should not be less than Column C
3. Column E should not be less than column C

I can put one but having issue while applying multiple as we can apply only one formula there.

Comment: Are these all date-time type columns? Is there any condition when you want to force these validations?

Answer (score 0):

use the `AND` function to validate multiple formulas at once, for example:

`=AND([ColumnA] >= [ColumnB], [ColumnF] >= [ColumnC], [ColumnE] >= [ColumnC])`